# Implementing NodeRED in NodeJS Webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, ibm-cloud

I have an unusual question:
Is it possible to integrate a NodeRED instance in a Node.JS website?
I want to implicate the instance as the bottom page where my users can create flow charts and see the result on another page.

Working Environment: Bluemix, Node.JS Express 4

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to embed nodeRED! It is fairly straightforward and the process is [well documented on the nodeRED site](http://nodered.org/docs/embedding).

It also sounds like it might be worth bearing in mind that all flows made in nodeRED exist as .json data in the main flow file (or you can manually save the separate workspaces). This makes it easy to parse and use this data in other pages as you see fit. The structure is very easy to read and understand when you glance through such files (and a tool like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json is very useful for manipulating that data).

Answer (score 0):

You can install NodeRed on any Node.js - follow the installation guide is [here](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation.html).

A complete setup guide can be found [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-hosting-node-red/what-is-node-red) (the device used here is a Raspberry Pi running Node.js, but the process is identical). You will need to parse the output from the NodeRed instance to 'show the result on another page' but should not be difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely you can initiate node-red from nodejs server please follow the [How to use Node-red with node](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/embedding)
but the best would be to wrap it with express.